# Pandas calculate new column based on condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have average watch time duration in secs, video length in secs and the day of the week for a list of shows.

```
    Week Day    Movie Name  Time Spent(seconds)     Duration sec    Week Number

0   Friday       Movie A    130.0                   1740.000000        4
1   Friday       Movie B    14665.0                 36278.000000       4
2   Friday       Movie C    26083.0                 166802.000002      4
3   Monday       Movie B    13515.0                 29290.000000       0
4   Monday       Movie C    21756.0                 136829.999999      0
5   Saturday     Movie A    94.0                    1680.000000        5
6   Saturday     Movie B    31373.0                 64092.000000       5
7   Saturday     Movie E    615.0                   2640.000000        5
8   Saturday     Movie D    175.0                   11940.000000       5
9   Saturday     Movie C    4671.0                  29340.000000       5
10  Sunday       Movie A    9238.0                  52797.000000       6
11  Sunday       Movie B    12016.0                 31332.000000       6
12  Sunday       Movie E    528.0                   2520.000000        6
13  Thursday     Movie A    212.0                   1860.000000        3
14  Thursday     Movie B    39018.0                 91197.000000       3
15  Thursday     Movie E    26402.0                 348991.000000      3
16  Thursday     Movie C    374.0                   4860.000000        3
17  Tuesday      Movie B    40456.0                 97607.000000       1
18  Tuesday      Movie C    7181.0                  29700.000000       1
19  Wednesday    Movie B    13243.0                 32093.000000       2
20  Wednesday    Movie D    1385.0                  34476.000000       2
21  Wednesday    Movie C    21256.0                 137097.999999      2
```

I want to calculate watch percentage of each show by weekday. I can easily conceptualize this in excel

```
SUM(average watch time)/SUM(video length for the weekday)
```

Edit: This is how I'm doing it as of now

```
result = []
for index, row in dff.iterrows():
    value = row["Time Spent(seconds)"]/dff.where(dff["Week Day"] == row["Week Day"])["Duration sec"].sum()
    result.append(value)
dff["Watch Time %"] = result
```

Summation of Weekday can be cached but notice the condition `dff["Week Day"] == row["Week Day"]`.

How can I get weekday and the sum of video length for the weekday based on the current row that pandas is working on? Is there an efficient way of doing it other than iterrows?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example with input data and expected output

Comment: if coming from SQL, always recommend to review pandas SQL comparison docs: [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/comparison/comparison_with_sql.html)

Comment: use datapart to get the week and then sum over partition based on the week and then calculate the average

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a dataframe that looks something like the following:

```
mdf = 
    Movie   Day Length  View_Time
0   A        2  2.6      1.8
1   A        3  2.6      2.6
2   B        1  5.8      2.9
3   A        4  2.6      2.6
4   B        6  5.8      4.2
5   A        0  2.6      0.5
6   B        3  5.8      2.0
```

You can compute the length per day by each movie as follows:

```
 mdf.groupby(['Movie', 'Day']).Length.sum().to_frame() 

Which produces a dataframe of the form:
              Length
Movie   Day 
A        0    2.6
         2    2.6
         3    2.6
         4    2.6
B        1    5.8
         3    5.8
         6    5.8
```